# Mysql - Group by month with unique subscriber user. User should not be repeated

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, unique, distinct

I have the following table with all subscriber users. I want unique subscriber user group by month but if user has already subscribed then should not be repeated in the count.

```
ID | USER   | CREATED DATE
1  | 1      | 2019-10-16
2  | 2      | 2019-10-18
3  | 3      | 2019-12-06
4  | 2      | 2020-01-01 (* This is repeated so should not be count in 01)
5  | 4      | 2020-01-05
6  | 5      | 2020-01-11
7  | 1      | 2020-02-14 (* This is repeated so should not be count in 02)
8  | 2      | 2020-03-06 (* This is repeated so should not be count in 03)
9  | 5      | 2020-03-15 (* This is repeated so should not be count in 03)
```

My expected output should be the following. Total users are 5 so the sum of total must be 5.

```
TOTAL   | MONTH
2       | 10
1       | 12
2       | 01
0       | 02
0       | 03
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `group by` to get the first month and then aggregate again:

```
select year(min_cd), month(min_cd), count(*)
from (select user, min(created_date) as min_cd
      from t
      group by user
     ) u
group by year(min_cd), month(min_cd);
```

This does not include the `0` values, but they seem somewhat arbitrary.

If you do want them with your data, then one method is window functions and conditional aggregation:

```
select year(min_cd), month(min_cd),
       sum( min_cd = created_date )
from (select user, min(created_date) over (partition by user) as min_cd
      from t
     ) u
group by year(min_cd), month(min_cd);
```

Comment: the second query throws an error
Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(partition by subscriber_user_id) as min_cd       from t      ) u group by year(' at line 3

Comment: @Ruchi . . . Window function are supported starting in MySQL 8.0.